# Regex to seperate two word linked by a full stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

I am processing a file and I found word which are linked by a full stop, I think it is an error and I want to correct it so I am looking for regex to do it.

```
['<repdns text="boys.aussi" />']
['<repdns text="interpretation.une" />']
['<repdns text="catastrophe.michelle" />']
['<repdns text="paquerettes.ewan" />']
['<repdns text="amour.hugh" />']
```

I actually read a file and use to treetagger to get the lemma but error like above appear so I need to correct them before using treetagger function. I am stuck on which regex to use because I do not want word with '.com', or '.org' to be seperate

```
a = [' boys.aussi', 'interpretation.une', 'amour.hugh', 'amy.com', 'frenchemabassy.net']

alphabet = "([a-z][...])"
alphabets = "([A-Za-z])"
prefixes = "(Mr|St|Mrs|Ms|Dr)[.]"
suffixes = "(Inc|Ltd|Jr|Sr|Co)[.]"
starters = "(M|Mr|Mme|Sr|Dr)"
acronyms = "([A-Z][.][A-Z][.](?:[A-Z][.])?)"
websites = "[.](com|net|org|io|gov)"
digits = "([0-9])"

# sÃ©pare les phrases

def normalize(text):  # do_lower=False):
    text = re.sub(alphabets + "[.]" + alphabets,)
    
    
    return text

normalize(a)
```

expectation

```
a = [' boys. aussi', 'interpretation. une', 'amour. hugh', 'amy.com', 'frenchemabassy.net']
```

Comment: _"because I do not want word with '.com', or '.org'"_ Be aware that '.com', '.org', and '.net' are not the only TLDs (top level domains). How are you going to make sure that the dot doesn't belong to one?

Comment: This might help?[`(\w+\.)(?!org|net|com)(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/GmymA6/21). Add other TLD's accordingly. Please do let me know if it helped.

Comment: And one case I wanna know too. What happens for `amy.co.in`?Does the string always contains only one `.`(period char)?

Comment: What do you expect to do with this line of code `text = re.sub(alphabets + "[.]" + alphabets,)` ?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to introduce language parts and web convention parts together. Parsing language with regex is really impossible. It doesn't matter if you name the variables language parts of speech, it just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *negative lookahead assertion* in your regex so that '.' is replaced with '. ' only if it is not followed by any of the special Internet top-level domain names:

```
import re

def normalize(text):
    return re.sub(r'\.(?!(com|net|org|io|gov))', '. ', text)

a = [' boys.aussi', 'interpretation.une', 'amour.hugh', 'amy.com', 'frenchemabassy.net']
a = [normalize(s) for s in a]
print(a)
```

Prints:

```
[' boys. aussi', 'interpretation. une', 'amour. hugh', 'amy.com', 'frenchemabassy.net']
```

Note that I am just using the list of TLDs you had in you `websites` variable; there are others you many want to add.